# Problem with <backend_model>

Tags: configuration, magento-1, backend, system.xml, core-config-data

I'm getting a little desperate here with my custom Magento Backend Models.

Here is the situation:
I have 2 multiselect (locales_served, countries_served) fields with custom backend models in my Magento Admin Configuration (as defined in system.xml below).
They are mutually exclusive depending on another yes/no field.

So far, so good. Everything works fine as expected, the backend models work, too, BUT when I switch from one multiselect to the other, it uses the other options backend model. The backend classes are completely separate and I have no clue what's happening.

Let's say I start with locales_served, select some options and save - it works fine, my values are stored in the DB, all good.
Then I go back to the Default Config, change to countries_served, select some options and save - BOOM, it overwrites my locales_served options.

```
<locales_served translate="label">
  <label>This Store serves these languages:</label>
  <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
  <backend_model>Foo_Bar_Model_LocaleMappingData</backend_model>
  <sort_order>5</sort_order>
  <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_locale</source_model>
  <show_in_default>0</show_in_default>
  <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
  <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
  <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
  <depends><redirection_mode_select>locale</redirection_mode_select
  </depends>
</locales_served>  

<countries_served translate="label">
  <label>This Store serves these countries:</label>
  <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type
  <backend_model>Foo_Bar_Model_CountryMappingData</backend_model
  <sort_order>4</sort_order
  <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
  <show_in_default>0</show_in_default>
  <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
  <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
  <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
  <depends><redirection_mode_select>ip</redirection_mode_select>
  </depends>
</countries_served>
```

Backend model class for locale select field:

```
class Foo_Bar_Model_LocaleMappingData extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data
{

const PATH = 'foo_bar/global_config/locales_served';


public function _afterSave()
{

    $h = Mage::helper('foo_bar/ConfigHelper'); 
    $storeId = $this->getScopeId();
    $h->updateMappings($storeId,$this->getValue(),self::PATH);  
}
}
```

backend model class for country select field, the echo produces this:
**'foo_bar/global_config/locales_served'** instead of **'foo_bar/global_config/countries_served'**

```
class Foo_Bar_Model_CountryMappingData extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data
{

const PATH = 'foo_bar/global_config/countries_served';


public function _afterSave()
{

echo self::PATH;
exit;
    $h = Mage::helper('foo_bar/ConfigHelper'); 
    $storeId = $this->getScopeId();
    $h->updateMappings($storeId,$this->getValue(),self::PATH);      
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you add the `updateMappings` methods to the question?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is impossible if you don't add `echo self::PATH` to the other class as well. `self::PATH` gets replaced with the constant in the **same class** at compile time (other than `static::PATH` which would be replaced at runtime)

So the actual code that is executed must be something else. Possible reasons:

- uploaded files to the wrong server / wrong location
- Opcache contains an old version of the code

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - `<depends>...</depends>` just converts the select field into a hidden field if the condition is not met - the value is still posted though and my backend model is still instantiated.